# Interoperability of RSA between VB.NET and PHP

Tags: php, vb.net, encryption, openssl, rsa

I use OpenSSL with PHP to generate Public/Private Key in PEM Format.

In PHP I create Public/Private Key :

```
// generate a 1024 bit rsa private key
$privateKey = openssl_pkey_new(array(
    'private_key_bits' => 1024,
    'private_key_type' => OPENSSL_KEYTYPE_RSA,
));
// Save Private key
openssl_pkey_export_to_file($privateKey, 'privateKey');

// get the public key 
$keyDetails = openssl_pkey_get_details($privateKey);
// Save Public key
file_put_contents('publicKey', $keyDetails['key']);
```

In VB.NET I code this :

```
'Public Key
Dim sReader As String ="MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQCxYT5RaHelEBmk4Z7ppiVaPPBns/36sdY12F/AXETJVl2SYkjc672JMz ..... zQwIDAQAB"
Dim PublicKey As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sReader)
Dim Exponent As Byte() = {1, 0, 1}

    'Create a new instance of RSACryptoServiceProvider.
    Dim RSA As New RSACryptoServiceProvider()

    'Create a new instance of RSAParameters.
    Dim RSAKeyInfo As New RSAParameters()

    'Set RSAKeyInfo to the public key values. 
    RSAKeyInfo.Modulus = PublicKey
    RSAKeyInfo.Exponent = Exponent

    'Import key parameters into RSA.
    RSA.ImportParameters(RSAKeyInfo)

    'Create a UnicodeEncoder to convert between byte array and string.
    Dim ByteConverter2 As New UnicodeEncoding()

    'Create byte arrays to hold original, encrypted, and decrypted data.
    bytPlainText = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Data to Encrypt")
    bytCipherText = RSA.Encrypt(bytPlainText, False)
    Dim sEncrypt99 As String = Convert.ToBase64String(bytCipherText)
```

But I cant' decrypt "sEncrypt99" in PHP with the Private key

For the test I copied "sEncrypt99" in "$encryptedData1"

```
<?php
$privateKey = openssl_pkey_get_private('file://privateKey');
openssl_private_decrypt(base64_decode($encryptedData1), $sensitiveData2, $privateKey);

echo "sensitiveData = " . $sensitiveData2 . "<br>";
?>
```

No errors, $sensitiveData2 is empty. Strange ....
Where is the problem ?

Rem : Excuse for my poor english, I'm french ;)

Answer (score 0):

I would check that the modulus and exponent match between the openssl version of the public key, and the .NET version.

The RSAParameters.Modulus array needs to be exactly 128 bytes for a 1024-bit key. The DER bytes may have a leading zero-byte making it 129 bytes -- be sure *not* to include that. That .NET array must be exactly 128 bytes (for a 1024-bit key.)

I would dump the public key from openssl, and check the array. For example:

1. Get the public key alone from the private key file on the PHP/OpenSSL side:

   $ openssl rsa -in private-key.pem -pubout -out public-key.pem
2. Parse the public-key using openssl asn1parse:

   $ openssl asn1parse -in public-key.pem

   0:d=0  hl=3 l= 159 cons: SEQUENCE
   3:d=1  hl=2 l=  13 cons: SEQUENCE
   5:d=2  hl=2 l=   9 prim: OBJECT            :rsaEncryption

   16:d=2  hl=2 l=   0 prim: NULL
   18:d=1  hl=3 l= 141 prim: BIT STRING
3. Parse the BIT STRING which has the actual RSA public key in it (PKCS1 ASN.1 form):

   $ openssl asn1parse -in public-key.pem -strparse 18

   ```
       0:d=0  hl=3 l= 137 cons: SEQUENCE          
       3:d=1  hl=3 l= 129 prim: INTEGER           :B404886A7F0544C14AAE14EEE531A2D78122C9BFDB06E8C80433559A617FD159A05F8FD45500BBA63A1D07239C26BD8D32D3550D5DEAF7BF9C16D3E16BDE5A9BB56C378CB9E0E7DA9D3A5513482D74E1FDCCAC147D0E909D1B620598F710B437D50DE8F80D5F742B6DA6E2D2ED1BBEBF89A40546103A8451B59D8190633ACFA5
     135:d=1  hl=2 l=   3 prim: INTEGER           :010001
   ```

That array, starting at B4 04 88 ... (i.e. whatever value you see for your key) should match the byte array you are setting in the RSAParameters. I'm pretty sure that this order (i.e. DER order) is what you find in the RSACryptoServiceProvider modulus array (i.e. [0] = 0xb4, [1] = 0x04, etc.) Also, you can verify the exponent (the second integer showing above as 01 00 01.)

Answer (score 0):

I know this thread is slightly outdated but im attempting the exact same thing. I came across a problem with 'file://privateKey'. Scrap it and use fopen, or store the key in a variable. Worked for me :)